# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have written on premise share point code (to insert the values into the sharepoint list) in with the sharepoint server machine,Its executing with in the server am able to insert the data into the list, same i made as a EXE file.

Same EXE file am running in my local machine(out side the server machine), It not working showing as mentioned below error.

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Can any body will help on this.

Thanks,
Nagendra.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it local it needs Sharepoint so you have to run this on Sharepoint server itself. You can work with websservices to do this "remote".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms458094(v%3Doffice.14)